How to get auto-escaped Windows paths when pasting into Java string literal in VS Code?
I have a copy path problem when i edit java file in VS Code.
When i copy path and past in the code, its like this
String path = "D:\files\assemble.xml";

I prefer to past it like this
String path = "D:\\files\\assemble.xml";

Which setting should I edit?

Or maybe just don't worry about it and focus on more important aspects of your code

Single forward slashes work perfectly well and are less ugly than doubled backslashes

@Abra first link is related, but more general (core VS Code). there's a more specific answer for the Java language-support extensions. your second link is not VS Code. also, concerning g00se's comment, see also https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28344/26010

At least for the Red Hat Java VS Code extension, escaping/formatting things pasted into string literals should already exist courtesy of Pull Request Format content pasted into string literals #2703 (release circa 2023 January). There was a regression when VS Code 1.88 release (see issue ticket Java string paste not auto escape #3568), but that should be fixed now by Pull Request Adjust the document paste handling provider. #3570, which is released in version 1.30 of the Red Hat Java extension.
